# External monitor doesn't work when connected to Mac or PC

Tags: windows, mac, display, hdmi

I have a Samsung SyncMaster s20b350 that has worked perfectly when connected to my macbook up until today. I have ruled out the mini displayport to hdmi adapter as being faulty because it still doesn't work when connected with just hdmi to a windows computer. It's not the hdmi cable because it works with my xbox. The weird thing is it works when connected with an hdmi to micro usb port to a windows 8 tablet, but not through hdmi to a windows 8 pc. I have reset the monitor to factory setting and it still doesn't work. The windows 8 pc doesn't detect the monitor but the macbook does, but neither display a picture. Any ideas?

Edit: It seems that my monitor is not capable of switching to hdmi both while not connected to anything or connected to my macbook. When I try to switch the source to hdmi is quickly cycles back to analog in about half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will shed some light:

I have a PC in HDMI1 and my XBOX in HDMI2. The Xbox works fine, but anytime I switch back to the PC, I have to do this hotkey trick or unplug and plugin the HDMI cable again...

For the PC, I have to unplug the cable (from either end, doesn't matter) and replug it in. Then the monitor comes to life. So if I leave my PC on and turn off the monitor (or switch to another input), I always have to unplug the cable and plug it back in after turning the monitor back on.

After doing this for some time, I discovered I could also get the video working by running a little script that changes my Windows resolution. I setup a hotkey so now, I turn on my monitor (or switch over to HDMI1), wait a second or so, then hit the hotkey to get the image on my screen. I set up 2 hotkeys to change the resolution, and another to change it back.